# Array of Points Sorting in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I have a class 'Point'. I want to sort an array of points, but I want to use 2 "compare" functions (I want to take 2 arrays, one with the points sorted by X and the other by Y).
How can I make my class accept 2 comparing functions? Here's my code

```
static class Point implements Comparator<Point>{
    int x,y;
    int compareX(Point A , Point B){
        return A.x - B.x;
    }
    int compareY(Point A , Point B){
        return A.y - B.y;
    }
}
```

Comment: don't you already have 2 comparing functions?

Comment: The problem is I need to implement the 'compare' function which will be used in Arrays.sort(myArray)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having `Point` implement `Comparator`, have 2 `Comparator` constants which compare by x and y respectively.

```
static class Point {
  public static final Comparator<Point> X_COMPARATOR = Comparator.comparingInt(Point::getX);

  public static final Comparator<Point> Y_COMPARATOR = Comparator.comparingInt(Point::getY);
}
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure how should I use this Comparators. This does not work:


    
      
public Point sortByX(){
   return Arrays.sort(this,X_COMPARATOR);
  }

Comment: @epanicafrate `Point` is not an array. `Arrays.sort` takes an `Object[]` as the first arg. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-

Comment: I meant Collections.sort, not Arrays.sort, my bad. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: `Collections.sort` takes a `Collection` as the first arg, not a `Point`. What is the exact error you ar getting.

Comment: I am trying to do this:

    `Collections.sort(S,new Comparator<Point>() {

   public int compare(Point o1, Point o2) {
       return Integer.compare(o1.getX(), o2.getX());
   }
   });`
But the error I get is:
The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (Cmap.Point[], new Comparator<Cmap.Point>(){}).
Cmap is my main class.

Comment: @epanicafrate why would your sortByX function return a single point? `public Point sortByX()` <- does not make any sense whatsoever

Comment: @epanicafrate the error message says that `S` is of type `Cmap.Point[]`. So its not a Collection but an Array. So you should use Arrays.sort